# The Compiler Will Not Let Me Compare Types

Tags: swift

Why will this function not compile? The complaint is: Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type I.Type and T.Type.

```
   func checkTypeOf<I, T>(instance: I, type: T.Type) {
       print("\(instance) \(I.self === type ? "is" : "is not") a \(type)")
   }
```

In contrast, here is an example that compiles and runs:

```
class Dog {
    @objc static var whatADogSays : String = "woof"
}
class NoisyDog : Dog {
}

func typeTester(d:Dog, _ whattype:Dog.Type) {
    print("The \(d.dynamicType) \(d.dynamicType === whattype ? "is" : "is not") a \(whattype)")
}

typeTester(NoisyDog(), Dog.self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to constraint the parameters to `AnyType` as === only applies to AnyObject.

```
func checkTypeOf<I: AnyObject, T: AnyObject>(instance: I, type: T.Type) {
    print("\(instance) \(I.self === type ? "is" : "is not") a \(type)")
}
```

Here is how the `===` operator is defined

```
@warn_unused_result
public func ===(lhs: AnyObject?, rhs: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. Check out the contrasting example that I have added to my question.

Comment: Wait a minute; now I get it. Without the AnyObject constraint, T and I could be structs or enums; to which the === operator cannot be applied.

Comment: Done. Thank you, Mohamede.